# How can I access the http headers using python and selenium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python

I have a complex javascript-intensive application I wish for which I wish to use python and selenium for automated testing.  However, at the same time I need to have access to the http headers for both the request and response so I can do some security analysis as well.

Is there a way to integrate the use of selenium with the requests module so I have the best of both worlds?

Comment: This might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799228/how-to-get-status-code-by-using-selenium-py-python-code

Comment: It's possible with Selenium. Either use a proxy server to intercept the requests or launch the browser with a custom webextension to capture the requests/responses.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is an `e2e` testing solution which works well with what is happening in browsers. It automates anything working in browser- mimicking what the users would try to do.

Instead of combining the API tests in Selenium and checking for the headers, you should have a different set up for API Testing, using Python `requests` module or `Chakram` in JS.

It's a bad idea to combine two different types of tests in same.